# Elastic Search Closest match with space in fields

Tags: elasticsearch, search, fuzzy-search, fuzzy

I have data in elasticsearch fields which contains **"face mask"**, I am able to fetch this data with the following query with search_term set to "face", "face mask", "mask" and "face masks".

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": ${search_term},
                    "fields": [
                        "title^4",
                        "titleNgram^3",
                    ],
                    "fuzziness": "auto"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

What I am not able to achieve is when I query for **"facemask"** (no spaces in search_term) it does not return any document containing **"face"** or **"mask"**, but, it returns documents with fields containing **"facewash"**. Is there a way to achieve it?

Mapping is shared below

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "titleNgram": {
                    "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer",
                    "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "id": {
                    "index": false,
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping too?

Comment: added in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing the  `"search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer",` and reindex the data and use the same query and it should return you the expected results.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "titleNgram": {
                    "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer", --> remove this line.
                    "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "id": {
                    "index": false,
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: I tested it locally and it worked for me, below is the sample I used**

**Search query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "face mask",
      "fields": [
        "titlengram",
        "title"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**And it gives your expected doc**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "ngram",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.3014567,
        "_source": {
          "title": "face mask",
          "titlengram": "face mask"
        }
      }
```

Comment: My query string is "facemask" without any spaces. It is not working for me. I changed the mapping, can you check that?

Comment: @yousufiqbal i checked with my `facemask` and it gives me search result, I can't see your updated mapping without search analyzer

Comment: It worked, thanks. I was not updating mapping correctly.

Comment: @yousufiqbal glad it helped

Comment: Thanks! I am getting face mask, but the score is less than face wash, any idea regarding it?